# How does React SetState update state when comparing to a previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Given the example below, which is the pattern of passing a function to setState rather than the object-based alternative below it. 
I'm a little unclear on the mechanics of updating the state this way. Can anyone help clear it up?

```
submit(){
   this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return {showForm: !prevState.showForm}
   });
}
```

less suggested alternative:

```
submit(){
       this.setState({showForm: !this.state.showForm}
       });
    }
```

but what is the mechanism that lets it insert new state if its not old state.
I understand that the negated value is used to sort of coerce the state change, but `!prevState.showForm`, similar to `!this.state.showForm` seems like terse syntax and I'm unclear on the mechanics.

Is it that: if the state is the same, the value is falsey, so the state isnt updated, but if the state is different the value is truthey and so the state is updated?

Comment: If your state update is derived from what is currently in your state (e.g. you want to increment a `counter`), you should use the update function version and return an object with the updates to the state. If the update is *not* derived from what is currently in the state (e.g. setting the `value` from an `input` element in a `onChange` handler) then you can go with the object version. If `showForm` is not in state, it will be `!undefined` the first time, which is `true`.

Comment: ' If showForm is not in state, it will be !undefined the first time, which is true' 
so the purpose of this technique is to not have to instantiate a `form > input` element state as `null` or `''` but open a state object to capture it `onChange`

Comment: I would personally have `state = { showForm: true };` in the initial state so that your colleagues or you yourself in 6 months can see at a glance what state this component holds. But yes, you could imagine that you have many forms and you want to store a form id in e.g. `visibleForms` in `state = { visibleForms {} }`. This way you can toggle between `true` and `false` without explicitly setting it to a default value.

Comment: 'I would personally have state = { showForm: true }; in the initial state so that your colleagues or you yourself in 6 months can see at a glance what state this component holds.'
I agree.  Thanks.  If you want to submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `showForm` is not in state, it will be `!this.state.showForm` will equal to `!undefined` which is `true`. This way you can toggle between `true` and `false` without having an initial value in the state for a certain parameter.

I would personally have `state = { showForm: false };` in the initial state so that your colleagues or you yourself in 6 months can see at a glance what state this component holds.